# Is it possible to supply value directly to cast()?

Tags: r, reshape

I would like to supply some value derived from the data frame to the `cast()` function without actually having to save it in the `data.frame`. As I understand it, I have to do this:

```
df$value <- ifelse(df$x > 0, 1, 0)
cast(df, row ~ col, value = "value")
```

I would actually like to do something like this:

```
cast(df, row ~ col, value = ifelse(df$x > 0, 1, 0))
```

but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

I could possibly do this:

```
cast(cbind(df, list(value = ifelse(df$x > 0, 1, 0))), row ~ col, value = "value")
```

but feels a bit clumsy.

EDIT: I found that the clumsy solution above can be simplified:

```
cast(cbind(df, value = ifelse(df$x > 0, 1, 0)), row ~ col)
```

still has the scent of clumsy hack though.

Comment: `cast` is deprecated. You should use `dcast`. Also `value.var` can not take an expression, it is just expecting a value or more in `names(df)`.

Comment: @agstudy 1) `cast` is *not* deprecated. Both `reshape` and `reshape2` are still maintained, one can choose from both. If you don't agree, please cite official sources 2) if you know the answer you are free to post `dcast` solution, but I am afraid it has the same limitations.

Comment: Why don't you provide some sample data so everyone can easily test ideas?

Comment: @TMS , why official sources? I am not the code maintainer. Maybe the package is still  maintained but usually people here use `reshape2`. Solution using dcast : `dcast(transform(df ,value =ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)),row~col,value.var="value")`

Comment: @agstudy, 1) If you state something as strong as "cast is deprecated, you should use dcast", this is simply not true. You shouldn't spread such statements without having this information from official sources. If you say "usually people here use reshape2", that's much better. 2) this is almost the same as I posted, thanks for `transform` though, it is more elegant!

Comment: @TMS ok. From the official [github page of `reshape` package](https://github.com/hadley/reshape), (by the way it redirects  you to reshape2 package) is clearly stated that: "Reshape2 is a reboot of the reshape package".Maybe deprecated is a strong statement, but since i am here in SO, when people ask question about reshape package they automatically redirected to a reshape2 solution.

Comment: @agstudy 1) found out that `cbind` can be actually used this simple way as well, so I consider it better than `transform` - as it is shorter. See my update.